# Is it possible to replace the Surface RT NVIDIA 1.4 GHz Tegra 3 Processor with an Intel i5 or i7?

Tags: windows-8, cpu, microsoft-surface

Tear down difficulty aside, is it possible to simply remove the NVIDIA 1.4 GHz Tegra 3 Processor in a Surface RT and replace it with an Intel i5 or i7? I admit I am not much of a hardware guy (probably painfully obvious), but if you can change the processor, you should be able to install a full-version of 8.1, correct? The Windows RT operating system is my only knock on the Surface RT, but not enough so to shell out a grand for one of the newer models.

Comment: No; it's not possible not even remotely possible.  ARM and x86 hardware is not even the Species

Comment: Care to elaborate? If anything, educate me. What are the hardware differences? I was under the assumption that the processor was the difference, but apparently that is false.

Comment: ARM handles devices differently than x86.  There is plenty of information on x86 and ARM that you should read.  You will not be able to remove the ARM processor and even if you did a x86 processor is not compatible with any of the hardware in the Surface RT.

Comment: In addition, you would have to replace most, if not all, of the software. Windows RT is specially made for the ARM platform. One would have to put Windows 8(.1) (maybe Windows 7 might work also?), and at that point, there's no guarantee of hardware compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Think about motherboards for desktop computers: they can work with multiple kinds of processors, but not all of them. Processor has to use the same socket type and needs support in motherboard's BIOS. Different sockets are required because different CPUs have different sets of pins. These motherboards are designed to work with different CPUs. These CPUs are designed to be compatible with each other, too.

Now, neither Surface's CPU nor motherboard are designed to be compatible with others. Furthermore, it's a totally different kind of CPU than i5 or i7. I'm 100% sure that (for example) i5-5200U is incompatible with Surface's ARM, because it's not even compatible with i5-460M which is *way* more similar.

Also, Surface's CPU is actually a SoC (System on Chip). It contains CPU, GPU, RAM and some other stuff packed in one die. Intel's Core processors (i3, i5, i7) all require external RAM.

All in all, the answer is: **You definitely can't replace *any* ARM with *any* x86 CPU**.